# if explodable / else

Tags: php

I have a string which may or may not contain commas. If it does, I want it exploded into an array; if it doesn't, I still want the string saved to the new identifier. My code clearly doesn't work. Anyone have any better ideas?

```
if(explode(",", $_SESSION['shoparea']))
{
    $areas = explode(",", $_SESSION['shoparea']);
} else {
     $areas = $_SESSION['shoparea'];
}
```

What is the correct syntax for this operation?

Comment: You can just explode it either way. If there is no comma in it you will have an array with 1 element in it.

Comment: Why do you want it as a string if it does not contain comma?

Answer (score 4):

```
if(strpos($_SESSION['shoparea'], ',') !== false) {
    $areas = explode(',', $_SESSION['shoparea']);
} else {
     $areas = $_SESSION['shoparea'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything can be exploded, if there are no instances of the delimiter it becomes a singleton array, so it may be simpler to do

```
$result = explode(",", $_SESSION['shoparea']);
if (count($result) == 1)
   $areas = $result[0];
else
   $areas = $result;
```

Comment: With that said, though, there ought to be a damn good reason to treat the two cases differently.  Why must the data either be (an item) or (a list of items), as opposed to (a list containing one item)?

Comment: @cHao Isn't messing with the mind of you colleagues (/ fellow developers) a damn good reason ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use http://php.net/strpos function to ensure that ',' are present.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is

```
$_SESSION['shoparea'] = "xx"; // Test value .. 

if (!$areas = explode(",", $_SESSION['shoparea'])) {
    $areas = array($_SESSION['shoparea']);
}
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'xx' (length=2)
```

**Note : `$areas` needs to always be array .. if you are using a loop you might have issue so i converted it ..**

Comment: -1. `explode` only returns false if the delimiter is an empty string: http://se2.php.net/explode

Comment: It would be nice for you to test it .... Here : http://codepad.viper-7.com/SMGD06  :)

Comment: Ok, +/-0. Now I understand what you are doing. It's still quite pointless. The if-statement will never return true. Simply using `$areas = explode(",", $_SESSION['shoparea'])` achieves the same thing.

Comment: You need need `array($_SESSION['shoparea']);` because `$areas` needs to be array ... if he is using a loop on `$areas` that might generate errors

Comment: That is, **IF** he is using a loop on $areas. The OP does not say anything at all what happens after his code. He does however specify what he wants - which is for the $areas variable to be a string after his code snippet.

Comment: It would be forced to use is_array or is_string .... ???  Consistency is good code practice .... that is what you should promote ...

Answer (score 1):

you could do this for examle

```
$areas = $_SESSION['shoparea'];
if(strpos($areas, ',') !== false) {
    $areas = explode(",", $areas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (substr_count($_SESSION['shoparea'], ',') > 0) {
    $areas = explode(",", $_SESSION['shoparea']);
}
else {
    $areas = $_SESSION['shoparea'];
}
```